# Execute the output of sed as a bash script that takes inputs

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

```
sed 's/docker/sudo docker/g' ./generate.sh | xargs bash
```

I want to run a script `generate.sh` with all `docker` calls replaced with `sudo docker`, as just as it would have been ran if I called `bash generate.sh`. It takes user input too, so how do I get it working? I cannot save any files, I can only use terminal.

Comment: I think this what you are looking for: `sed 's/docker/sudo docker/g' ./generate.sh |  bash` (just remove `xargs`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon thanks, but I cannot give inputs to the script when it asks me. I need it interactively; exactly as running bash ./generate.sh.

Comment: Why can you not give input? The input that you should get is necessary to provide the `sudo password`. Btw to avoid using `docker` with sudo, you can add your user to `docker` group, like this: `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`. After that, just logout or login with `su - $USER` and you will be able to use docker without using sudo.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I use podman, so do you know if adding to `docker` group will work?

Comment: I don't think so, for podman is different AFAIK. Just for curiosity, why if you are using podman the script you want to run is about docker ? Adding the user to docker group will allow the user run docker commands without using sudo

Comment: @EdgarMagallon: If you run a command like `sed 's/docker/sudo docker/g' ./generate.sh |  bash` then the standard input of `bash` will be the pipe from `sed`, which can be problematic if your script expects standard input to come from the terminal (eg for getting input from the user).

Comment: Note that using `g` in your `sed` command will do what you want for commands like `docker compose some_file` or `docker ...; docker ...` (or with `&` or `&&` but will not work as intended for a command like `docker compose docker_files/some_file`. People tend to use `g` as a matter of habit when it's not needed.

Comment: @psmears thanks! I got it now, I was misunderstanding and did not consider that `./generate.sh` could read user input (such as `read varname...`). That makes sense for me :).

Answer (score 5):

If, as you commented on @Freddy's now deleted answer it's also important that the path of the temporarily generated script be in the current working directory as the script looks for other resources relative to its own path, something like this wouldn't work:

```
bash <(sed 's/docker/sudo docker/g' ./generate.sh)
```

As the path of the script would then be something like `/dev/fd/63` or `/tmp/some-temporary-named-pipe`, and the script would be looking for resources in `/dev/fd` or `/tmp` instead of the current working directory where `generate.sh` lies.

However, in zsh, you could do:

```
TMPPREFIX=$PWD/.transformed-
bash =(sed 's/docker/sudo &/g' ./generate.sh)
```

Where the `=(...)` form of command substitution uses temp files instead of `/dev/fd/x` and pipes and can be told how to name them with the `$TMPPREFIX` and `$TMPSUFFIX` variables.

Or with the variable modified `local`ly only in an anonymous function:

```
() { local TMPPREFIX=$PWD/.transformed-
bash =(sed 's/docker/sudo &/g' ./generate.sh)
}
```

In bash, maybe you could do:

```
docker() { sudo docker "$@"; }
export -f docker
bash ./generate.sh
```

Instead to redefine `docker` as a function that calls `sudo docker`.

Beware however, that that exported function will end up also being exported to other commands run by that script.

It may be wise to unexport it upon first use to limit the risk that they propagate further:

```
docker() {
  typeset -f +x docker
  sudo docker "$@"
}
export -f docker
bash ./generate.sh
```

Note that in any case, exported functions don't survive across `sudo` (thankfully!).

Or use:

```
bash -c 'docker() { sudo docker "$@"; }; . ./generate.sh'
```

Which would even work in `sh` (that `.sh` extension would suggest it's rather a sh script):

```
sh -c 'docker() { sudo docker "$@"; }; . ./generate.sh' ./generate.sh
```

where the second `./generate.sh` is passed as the inline script's `$0`   (which is probabably where your script gets the idea of what its own path is).

If the script is short enough, you may be able to pass `sed`'s output as a whole as the inline script:

```
bash -c "$(sed 's/docker/sudo &/g' ./generate.sh)" ./generate.sh
```

When in ksh emulation, `zsh` can interpret most bash scripts and zsh lets you redefine `$0`, so you could do:

```
zsh --emulate ksh <(
  echo '0=./generate.sh'; sed 's/docker/sudo &/g' ./generate.sh)
```